# continuous and odd function from the n-sphere

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $f : S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, odd function. Want to show that $f$ has a zero.

I have done this for $S^1$ by using connectedness of $S^1$ and the intermediate value theorem. However I am not quite sure on how to extend the result to $S^n$

Answer (score 2):

Since $S^n$ contains a copy of $S^1$ you can just restrict $f$ to that copy and use your result for $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by odd function you mean $f(a(x))=-f(x)$, where $a: S^n\to S^n$ is the antipodal map. Assume WLOG that $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0\in S^n$. Then $f(a(x_0))<0$. Apply intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.